# Using nServiceBus' createInstance on an interface containing an array - how do I instantiate the array?

Tags: nservicebus

I have an event defined as follows:

```
public interface IClass
{
     DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
     IChild[] Children { get; set; }
}

public interface IChild
{
     string From { get; set; }
     string To { get; set; }
     decimal ADecimal { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to use the following syntax

```
bus.send<IClass>(class=> 
{
    class.EffeciveDate = DateTime.now;
    class.Children = //Not sure what to do here
}
```

How do I go about instantiating the array and populating the child objects?

Answer (score 0):

`Child` doesn't need to be an interface to use createinstance on the event.

Have you tried:

```
public interface IClass
{
     DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
     Child[] Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
     string From { get; set; }
     string To { get; set; }
     decimal ADecimal { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
Child someArray = Child[] { ... some items ... }    

bus.send<IClass>(class=> 
{
    class.EffeciveDate = DateTime.Now;
    class.Children = someArray;
}
```

Comment: Good point, that would potentially work. But I'd like for child to be an interface as it could potentially be a message in itself.

Comment: NSB doesn't prevent the publishing of concrete classes; "events are interfaces" appears in practicality to be only a convention.  Any way that you choose to instantiate the IClass interface  should also work.  You should be able to use bus.CreateInstance<IClass>() if you really want.

But I wouldn't.  It's tempting when you include interfaces in an event to use polymorphism.  NSB's proprietary serialization will not include any subclass properties.

Because you can't usefully derive from IClass, it would then only be an interface for the sake of NSB convention and not behave as expected in c#.

Comment: Thanks. Using CreateInstance<IClass> is, as I understand, the same as bus.send<IClass> and that's what I'm  having issues with. There are reasons beyond the scope of this question why I'm choosing to use Interfaces.